# Is it safe to use an AD account to run an App Pool in IIS in order to provide SQL read/write permissions to a web app?

Tags: web-application, active-directory, iis, sql-server

I've been working on an intranet web application that provides read/write, role-based access to a database.

I have been asked to configure the IIS application to use an AD account for the Application Pool, in order to provide the database permissions.  The reason for this is to avoid giving read/write access to the individual users.

I'm concerned about the possibility of malicious code being added to the server, and then having access to the database by virtue of the app pool.  Is this a valid concern?  Are there other risks or concerns with this approach?

Comment: As long as it is a service account that is used and the principle of least privileges is properly applied, this shouldn't be much of a risk on the application pool. I am uncertain what you mean by "if malicious code is added to the server" part, this obviously is a concern. Perhaps you can describe the process of how code is released on this server?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I know there are several apps on this server; I do not know how they were developed or deployed. I'm new to the organization, which has been without a web developer for a while. My app is developed on my local workstation, and then copied to the server via RDP connection for deployment. Our IS Security team will perform a security audit once I've deployed, but I'd like to be as proactive as possible in identifying potential issues before the audit.

Comment: Does every application has its own application pool and thus their own service account on the server that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

> From my point of view your concern is valid.  And managing access from
>   your IIS web server to your SQL server database with such
>   configuration is a good approach. It is also true that if your web
>   server is compromised by a malicious code execution ([source](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3186758/security/millions-of-websites-affected-by-unpatched-flaw-in-microsoft-iis-6-web-server.html)),
>   attacker could elevate privileges, collect credentials, impersonate any IIS App Pool account and get access to your SQL Server. I can suggest the following and specific security recommendations to increase your architecture security :

**Lifecycle management for service account:**

- Define a password policy rotation to frequently change passwords (some *Password Access Management* solutions can address this problem)
- Use complex password policy
- To reduce workload from previous points, use *Managed Service Accounts* ([source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/)). They will provide accounts with complex passwords and automatic rotation
- Respect the least privilege (as mentioned by @Jeroen) for each of you App Pool and never grant full admin or DB admin privileges to a service account
- Use Kerberos authentication (not activated per default). This will require several configuration ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/)) and usage of SPNs

**Server security:**

- Enable Windows advanced logging and *PowerShell logging* to detect strange behaviors (like new process, application crash, failed logons, new service, lateral movement...)
- Enable *SQL Server* logging
- Enable IIS logs (txt format files)
- Do not store front end servers in the same network or subnet than your sensitives servers (eg: database servers, AD, PKI, ...) and use a firewall to filter only the necessary traffic (in your case the port used by your SQL instance).
- Switch your IIS server to Core mode ([source](https://4sysops.com/archives/internet-information-services-iis-on-server-core/)) to reduce its surface exposition

> So at the end there is no "magic" solution to address your issue, except following basic and advanced security best practices. Having a log collector (eg: SIEM) in place will be also helpful to increase your security coverage from all your logsources (firewall, Windows, Linux, Unix, routers, IDS, IPS, ...).

Comment: Are you quoting from somewhere?  If you are, you should give the citation and/or link.  If not, why is it blockquotes?